# backbutton listener prevents default action automatically

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs

I'm building an app with Cordova and AngularJS and I added the code below in my run block but it doesn't work as I wish. My goal is to prevent the default action of the backbutton event **only in certain cases**, but as soon as I add the listener the back button has no more effect at all! I've tried removing all the conditions but the problem persists. As soon as I "listen" to the backbutton event, it never goes back.

```
document.addEventListener('backbutton', function(evt) {
   if (condition) {
     evt.preventDefault();
   }
}
```

I tested under Android 6.0.1, Angular 1.4.3 and Cordova 6.3.1.

Any ideas?

Comment: use `onBackPressed()` instead

Comment: I don't think I can use that with Cordova.